# Generating files to multiple paths with Swagger Codegen?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, .net-core, swagger-codegen

I'm creating a template for our server-side codegen implementation, but I ran into an issue for a feature request...

The developers who are going to use the generated base want the following pattern (the generator is based on the dotnetcore):

- Controllers

  - v{apiVersion}

    - {endpoint}ApiController : Controller, I{endpoint}Api
- Interfaces

  - v{apiVersion}

    - I{endpoint}Api
    - I{endpoint}DataProvider
- DataProviders
  -v{apiVersion}
   -{endpoint}DataProvider : I{endpoint}DataProvider

Both interfaces are the same, describing the endpoints. The DataProvider implementation will allow us to use DI to hot-swap the actual data provider/business logic layer during runtime.

The generated ApiControllers will refer to the IDataProviders, and use the actual implementation (the currently active one, that is). For that we're going to use dotnetcore's built-in dependency injection system.

However I can't seem to find a way to have the operations generator output to three different folders, based on the template. It will all end up jumbled in a single folder, and I will need to manually move them.

Is there a way to solve these requirements, or should I solve it all the time manually?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way of doing this, the folders structure is defined by the classes in the main module, not in the templates. A good starting point would be modifying https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AspNetCoreServerCodegen.java but you might need to go deeper.

Comment: @fonix232 did you managed to find a solution for this?